# Not able to record vugen script

Tags: performance, loadrunner

I have to record an application which is requesting client side certificate. So I recorded a script with the following options:

socketlevel and winInetlevel in port mapping
disable the option "detect SSL version"

I'm able to record the script successfully but when I replay it, I'm getting the below error:
Error -27778: [GENERAL_MSG_CAT_SSL_ERROR]connect to host "cuvwa00a0558.ent.wfb.bank.qa" failed: [10054] Connection reset by peer [MsgId: MERR-27778]

So I added a function 'web_set_sockets_option("SSL_VERSION", "TLS");' and verified. This time I started getting the different error:

Error -27769: Cannot set Certificate File "WinINetCert1.pem". File format is probably invalid (should be ASN1 or PEM).

where in we already have .pem file in script folder. please suggest any solution for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it definitely meant to be TLS?
Have you verified the .PEM file works through other means?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've posted your question at the [HP forum](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Forum/Not-able-to-record-vugen-script/td-p/6756147#.VYjxSEYyiap) as well, so let's continue the discussion there.